# Как написать правильно функцию: что бы текст помещает в файл "image_text.txt"

Tags: python

Как написать правильно функцию: если пользователь произнесет эту команду «Write File», то программа считывает текст с изображения и весь текст помещает в файл "image_text.txt";

Мне кажется, я что то не то сделал, поправьте меня пжл.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def sayToMe(talk):
    engine.say(talk)
    engine.runAndWait()

sayToMe('Hello!')

result = ''
while result != 'exit':

    sayToMe('Com mand, please !')

    record = sr.Recognizer()
    try:
        with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
            print('Speak English, please! ...')
            audio = record. listen(source)
            result = record.recognize_google(audio, language="en—En")
            result = result.lower()
            print(result)

            if result == 'write file':
                text = image_to_string(Image.open('images/photo.png'))
                print(text)
                file = open('date/image_text.txt', 'w')
                file.write('text')
                file.close()

            elif result == 'read file':
                text = image_to_string(Image.open('image_text.txt'))
                print(text)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Your speech is not recognized")
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: StackOverflow is English-only site. Please translate or ask at [ru.so].

Comment: How to write a function correctly: if the user says this command "Write File", the program reads the text from the image and puts the entire text in a file "image_text.txt ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, что если предоставите больше информации, то помощь придет скорее,
вы могли бы поделиться списком библиотек, которые вы используете в вашем requirements.txt (или pyproject.toml), а также предоставить видео экрана с демонстрацией того, что у вас получается сейчас.

И просто предположение, возможно, что сервис
Google Cloud API могли бы облегчить вам решение данной задачи:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text - голос в текст

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr - надписи на изображениях в текст

Comment: Не совсем понимаю причем тут библиотеки.., вот что я установил: pip install pipwin,
pipwin install pyaudio, pip install pytesseract

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно ошибка в том, что ты сравниваешь ответ звукового движка со словами с большими буквами, то есть приведи ответы к нижнему регистру, не исспользуй пунктуацию (тк распознаване речи её не исспользует), установи язык ввода в распознавателе речи

Comment: Как раз верхний регистр или нижний не влияет на разговор ИИ. У меня работает разговор и ответы, не могу добиться записи в файл. Что то не то сделал, скорее всего. ..